# How can I hide cite to references without deleting them from text?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, cross-referencing

I need to hide the cite to the references in a large text file. Is there a function that hides the cite to the references without manually deleting them from the text

Example

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=numeric, 
  sortcites,
  backend=biber,
  giveninits=true % <===================================================
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} % <============================


\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
This document is an example of BibTeX using in bibliography management. 
Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book 
\cite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein journal paper \cite{einstein}, and 
the Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related 
items are \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

How can I hide cite to references without deleting them from text?

As this picture 
[image]

Comment: Try `\citetitle{latexcompanion}` instead of `\textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change the cite command to do nothing using `\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}{}{}{}{}`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=numeric, 
  sortcites,
  backend=biber,
  giveninits=true % <===================================================
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} % <============================

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}{}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
This document is an example of BibTeX using in bibliography management. 
Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book 
\cite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein journal paper \cite{einstein}, and 
the Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related 
items are \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Answer (score 9):

You can use `\nocite` instead of `\cite`. But you have to delete the blanks before `\nocite` like this:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=numeric, 
  sortcites,
  backend=biber,
  giveninits=true 
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} 


\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
This document is an example of BibTeX using in bibliography management. 
Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}
book\nocite{latexcompanion}, % <========================================
the Einstein journal paper\nocite{einstein}, % <========================
and the Donald Knuth's website\nocite{knuthwebsite}. % <================
The \LaTeX\ related 
items are\nocite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. % <======================

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

So you can use `\cite{key}` if you need the citing in the text or `\nocite{key}` to get only the entry `key` added to the bibliography ...

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem I have faced when I were working on Reference section. Then, I have solved it by using
`\nocite{}`
command.  `\nocite{}` command is working  perfectly for removing citation info from text.